DrawingVisual swallowing inputs
I have a Canvas with a single instance of a custom class called a VisualHost added. As you can see in the implementation, I expose and pass around the drawing context of a DrawingVisual and draw a bunch of stuff into there.
Using Snoop, I then see which controls handle a PreviewMouseWheel event. I can see all of the controls that participate in the event tunneling when I scroll over the canvas...but when I place the cursor over the drawn content of the VisualHost, the scroll event doesn't even register in Snoop. The overridden handler shown in the code below never fires. I can spin the wheel all day over the drawn geometry and nothing.
My understanding is that VisualHost would serve as the input-detector when input events occur over the visual content of the VisualHost instance since it is a class inherited from UIElement, so I must be missing some intermediate step to connect the rendered visual content ownership to the UIElement level inside the class. What am I missing?
internal class VisualHost:UIElement
{
    internal DrawingVisual MyVisual { get; init; } = new DrawingVisual();
    internal DrawingContext RenderOpen()=> MyVisual.RenderOpen();

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(e);
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => MyVisual;

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;

}



See the duplicate question. Note that for receiving input events, using a VisualCollection is sufficient. The manual hit testing may not be required in your case.

@Clemens thank you, the use of VisualCollection instead of the single DrawingVisual did indeed fix the issue and began detecting input events.
